# How can I store output string to a variable AND display in console

Tags: perl, makefile, gnu-make

I have a perl script that prints a message. This script is being called by GNU make. In my GNU make, I want to display the message printed out by the script AND store it in a variable also.

I'm doing it this way.

```
 result=`$(PERL) parse.pl report.log` #parse the report
 echo $(result) #echo the message here
 ifneq ($(strip $$(result)),) #check if message is empty
   #if not empty, search for filepath string pattern and exit
   echo filepath
   exit 1
 endif
```

But it is not displaying the string message from parse.pl.

Comment: what do you want to do later with the captured line?  show that part of your Makefile too.  you are capturing into a shell variable, but then trying to echo a makefile variable (and even if you tried to echo the shell variable, that wouldn't work because make runs each line in a separate shell process).

Comment: i have updated with more details. I haven't figured out how to do regex on $result yet, so would be glad for any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are capturing into a shell variable, but then trying to echo a makefile variable (and even if you tried to echo the shell variable, that wouldn't work because make runs each line in a separate shell process).

Changing it to echo the shell varible and all to run in one shell should work:

```
foo:
    result=`$(PERL) parse.pl report.log`; \
    echo $$result
```

but whatever you later need to do to use the captured result would also need to be in the same shell execution.

Apparently you can capture into a makefile variable too, which may be more convenient:

```
foo:
    $(eval result := $(shell $(PERL) parse.pl report.log))
    echo $(result)
```

Comment: hmm.. nothing also gets displayed with this.

Comment: thanks! it works now. must I always refer to result as $$result? I want to check if it is empty or not. if I add this line "ifeq($(strip $$(result)),)", i get this error: "/bin/sh: -c: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `$(result),'
/bin/sh: -c: line 2: `ifeq ($(result),) \'"

Answer (score 0):

The critical thing to keep in mind with make is first, that the entire makefile is parsed before any rules are run, and second a makefile has two completely distinct syntaxes in it: makefile syntax for most of it, and shell syntax for the recipes.  The shell syntax is run by the shell, not by make: make just starts a shell, hands over the recipe, and waits for the shell to exit to see if it worked or not.

As a result of this you CANNOT combine make constructs like `ifeq` with shell commands and their results: it cannot work because all the make constructs are parsed first, while the makefile is being read in, and the shell commands are not run until much later, when the target is to be built.

In your case you need to write the entire thing in *shell* syntax, because you want things to depend on the shell invocation.

So, like this:

```
foo:
        result=`$(PERL) parse.pl report.log`; \
        echo $$result; \
        if [ "$$result" = "" ]; then \
            echo filepath; \
            exit 1; \
        fi
```

Note how each line ends with a backslash, so it's appended to the previous line instead of being a separate line: make runs each separate line in a different shell.

Alternatively if you have a new-enough GNU make you can use the [one shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/One-Shell.html) feature:

```
.ONESHELL:
foo:
        result=`$(PERL) parse.pl report.log`
        echo $$result
        if [ "$$result" = "" ]; then
            echo filepath
            exit 1
        fi
```